# Take out JSON elements out of Socket MQTT in Flask

Tags: python, json, flask, socket.io, mqtt

I'm currently using [MQTT-Flask](https://github.com/stlehmann/Flask-MQTT/) to accomplish sending a payload over MQTT and sockets to my Flask webserver. So far it works well, and I've been attempting to build on what I have and transition the payload into JSON to pack more data into it, so that I can use the variables on different parts of the site.

That said, I'm not able to save have it been recognized as JSON so that I can save the variables from it, and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

So the snippet of data I use in Flask looks as follows:

```
@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    data = dict(
        topic=message.topic,
        payload=message.payload.decode(),
    )
    socketio.emit('mqtt_message', data=data)
```

as came standard with the github, and I saw no fault with this, so I kept it.

On the template/index.html it looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='socket.io.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    socket.on('mqtt_message', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#mqtt_msg').text(data.payload);
    })
  });
</script>

<div id="mqtt_msg"></div>
```

I've tried parsing it into JSON.stringify and just trying to take it out as data.timestamp but all of that doesn't seem to work. It feels like it is very straightforward.

The payload I'm pushing looks as follows:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1614708210,
    "payload": "432",
    "agent": "web_admin"
}
```

Any help or input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create JSON string while sending data

```
socketio.emit('mqtt_message', data=json.dumps(data))
```

parse the JSON string on the client-side

```
socket.on('mqtt_message', (data) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

Don't forget to import `json` package in python

```
import json
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I understand correctly, this would format the JSON before it's being sent over socket - but I don't see a difference on the backend on how it looks. That said, after the client-side change, how do I display them on HTML? would I be able to use them as, say: data.timestamp? I was not able to make this work.

Comment: From the backend, I emit JSON data as a string. Then, on the frontend, I will create an object out of the JSON string that is sent from the backend. Now, I can access all the attributes of the object like `parsedData.payload.timestamp`. Assuming `const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);`. Displaying on HTML is a different question altogether.

Comment: I did some testing and tried a few things, such as putting that code in, but putting even in the json.dumps will break the code, no matter what I send through. Also, JSON.parse at the client-side, no matter what I put through seems to break it. I'm grateful for your help and suggestion but this does not seem to work for me at all.

Comment: You are not doing something right. It would be impossible to solve your issue unless the whole context is provided.